# Django Models Choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

> I have a tuple of choices for a model like this and I want to use the choices to be displayed in a Navbar, this is what I currently have:

**models.py**

```
OPCIONES_EVENTO = (
    ('A', 'Aniversario'),
    ('C', 'Cumpleaños'),
    ('P', 'Padre'),
    ('M', 'Madre'),
    ('B', 'Bautizo')
)

class Productos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    precio = models.FloatField()
    precio_descuento = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    categoria = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_CATEGORIA, max_length=1)
    etiqueta = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_ETIQUETA, max_length=1)
    tipo = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_TIPO,
                            max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    evento = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_EVENTO,
                              max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Productos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detalle-producto', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_agregar_al_carrito_url(self):
        return reverse('agregar-al-carrito', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_quitar_del_carrito_url(self):
        return reverse('quitar-del-carrito', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_filtro_evento(self):
        return reverse('filtro-evento', kwargs={'evento': self.evento})
```

**views.py**

```
class FiltroEvento(ListView):

    template_name = 'filtro-evento.html'
    model = Productos

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs['evento'] == 'B':
            evento = 'B'
            return Productos.objects.filter(evento=evento)
        elif self.kwargs['evento'] == 'C':

            evento = 'C'
            return Productos.objects.filter(evento=evento)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('productos/<evento>', views.FiltroEvento.as_view(), name='filtro-evento')
```

> This is part of the code for the html template:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'productos' %}">Todos
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            {% for producto in object_list %}
            {% if producto.get_evento_display %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ producto.get_filtro_evento}}">{{producto.get_evento_display}}</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
```

> Obviously that is returning the choices that already have been saved
> in the DB in 'Productos' is there a way to display the choices in
> general?

Comment: Why don't you send choices in context and render them in template?

Comment: hmmm good point, I didn´t think of that, let me see